# How to use the results of User Form in another macro?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a userform, lets say when I click the button name in the userform it will request me to enter a name and it is always stored in

```
private sub button_click()
  name = inputbox("Please enter your name:")
end sub
```

The thing I want is, when I start the macro first user form will appear then after user enters the necessary information, the variables values' will last until the end of the main macro.

I am searching for last two days couldn't find a solution but who knows maybe I couldn't find it. Therefore, i am writing here. Thanks in advance!

`
another question related:

lets say I have

```
    Public plant As Variant
Public checking As Variant
Public MeanCov1 As Variant
Public MeanCov2 As Variant
Public MeanCov3 As Variant
Public WeekCov1 As Variant
Public WeekCov2 As Variant
Public WeekCov3 As Variant
Public RolLow As Variant
Public RolHigh As Variant
Public ServiceLevel As Variant
Public TrendMultiplier As Variant
Public WeekCov11 As Variant
Public WeekCov22 As Variant
Public WeekCov33 As Variant

Sub initialize()
MeanCov1 = 0.3
MeanCov2 = 0.5
MeanCov3 = 0.7
WeekCov1 = 18
WeekCov2 = 13
WeekCov3 = 8
WeekCov11 = -14 + WeekCov1
WeekCov22 = -14 + WeekCov2
WeekCov33 = -14 + WeekCov3

RolLow = 0.3
RolHigh = 0.7

TrendMultiplier = 4

ROL_Analysis.Show
Application.Run ("ROL_Analysis_Macro")

End Sub
```

I can not initialize the public variables, for example in user form it says show variable values but when I click it is completely empty

```
Private Sub ROLparameter_Click()
Line1: RolLow = InputBox("Please enter the lower bound percentage for ROL calculation between 0 and 100 (initially " & RolLow & "%):")

If Not 0 <= RolLow <= 100 Then GoTo Line1

Line2: RolHigh = InputBox("Please enter the upper bound percentage for ROL calculation between 0 and 100 (initially " & RolHigh & "%):")


End Sub
```

Comment: You should write Option Explicit at the top of your code, in every module/userform. I'm not sure what you mean by initialize, but when if you want to check the value of a public variable in another module, say `Public strValue as String` written in Module1, and you want to access that in your userForm, you can specify `Module1.strValue` so it knows where to find it.

Answer (score 2):

To access a variable in a different sub, you define it globally

```
Public Name As String

Private Sub button_click()
    Name = InputBox("Please enter your name:")
End Sub

Sub Foo()
    MsgBox Name
End Sub
```

and for your second question, if you are clicking on the buttons, then for the below code you will get a alert if you have clicked the button which corresponds to the name you typed in the InputBox

```
Public name As String

Sub button_click()
    name = InputBox("Please enter your name:")
End Sub

Private Sub button1_click()
    If name = "john" Then
        MsgBox name
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub button2_click()
    If name = "james" Then
        MsgBox name
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub button3_click()
    If name = "david" Then
        MsgBox name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: not working, and how it supposed to work any way? There is no link between subs. And I can not put another sub in one sub, it will divide it. I can pass the variable with call subname but there are 3 different clicks refer to same variable so call does not give me any solution.

Comment: the variable 'Name' is defined as a global variable. when you run button_click, you enter the name and it is stored to the variable. and when you run Foo() the previously entered name will be alerted as 'Name' is defined global to be accessed by every Subs. And this is perfectly working for me

Comment: make sure you define the variable `name` as global outside all the subs `Public Name As String` and you will be able to access it in all the Subs

Comment: I am trying but it gives error when I try to define it since it is not in between any subs. If it works perfectly for you, i will try more, maybe i miss something. 

Can I ask another question?
lets say I have

private sub button1_click()
name=john
end sub

private sub button2_click()
name=james
end sub

private sub button3_click()
name=david
end sub


So the user has 3 marking options, when it clicks one of them it will go to one of the button clicks. Can I read only the name chosen with your method?

Comment: variable will hold the name from last clicked button. and when you are manually assigning the name like `name="john"` then make sure you are not missing `"`

Comment: your code is working on a empty module thats correct but I don't get anything useful for my situation unfortunately :( 

I define my variables public, but what happens next? How do I open the userform first than it will continue with the rest of the macro? Userform has a lot of subs so it is not what I expected. 

Also I couldn't initialize my public variables :/

Comment: look at my edited answer, and if this isn't what you are looking for, then it looks like i need to see your full code and understand what you are trying to do

Comment: look at `David G` answer, when i try to get the value of `WeekCov11` through a button in the user form `ROL_Analysis` i get the value as 4

Answer (score 1):

As was said, define a variable globally to access it in different subs and different modules. I have a very simple example here for you. I created a module called Module1. Here is all its code:

```
Option Explicit
Public name As String

Sub Test()
    name = "David"
    UserForm1.Show
    MsgBox "The userform has closed"
End Sub
```

I also created a userform called UserForm1. Here is all the code and a screenshot of it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Module1.name
End Sub
```

[image]

**How it works:**

If I launch Module1, the `public` variable `name` gets set to "David". In your case you could set it to whatever you want with your inputbox. After that, the userform is launched with `.Show` and the Module1 stops reading code until you're done with UserForm1.

While Userform1 is active, clicking the button will open a MsgBox saying "David", because I access the public variable `Module1.name`. I always specify which module the public variable comes from. When I close the userform, Module1 gets activated again and I get a msgbox saying "The userform has closed".

Does this answer all your questions?

Clicking the button:

[image]

Closing the form:

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the `name` variable with the userform, you can use `Module1.name =  "something"` at any time and it will last after the userform closes as well. For example, you could have a `public intCounter as integer` in Module1 and clicking a button will increment `Module1.intCounter`. At the end of Module1 if you ask a msgbox to show `intCounter` it will show it properly even though the form is closed.

Comment: First, thanks for all the effort. I initialize it because I used this macro before userform. So the variables has initial values if the user leave inputbox blank. We can say their default values. So I will put 3 option button, user can choose the country. When the user choose the canada option, the country variable should be canada now on. Think that there is one big macro with working canada variable before, now the same macro should open the user form, get the input and should continue with this input. If i used call, the answer will change depending on my call rather than choice.

Comment: So if your public string, say "strCountry", is declared in module1, and that is also where you have your macro. In the click event of the button on the userform, write `Module1.strCountry = "Canada"` So everytime someone clicks the "Canada" button, it will change the public string to "Canada". If it's not a button but it's a list, and Canada is one of the values, in the click event, you would write something like "Module1.strCountry = MyList.Value". If the value was "Canada" when the user clicked it, the strCountry is now worth "Canada", if it was "India", then strCountry is worth "india", etc

Comment: Private Sub ROLparameter_Click()
Line1: RolLow = InputBox("Please enter the lower bound percentage for ROL calculation between 0 and 100 (initially " & RolLow & "%):")

If Not 0 <= RolLow <= 100 Then GoTo Line1


End Sub

Comment: Could you look at the code above also? I don't know why but if function not working properly. (I can not change its view to code therefore i will add to main question also.) So when I enter the variable RolLow, it should check if it is in the defined range. But it is not checking. If i put "if" it is always asking, if i put "if not" it always takes it true. It also not accepting the end if saying that "endif without if". Do you know why?

Comment: Did you manage to make your original question work with what I wrote in my answer? If yes, please mark it as accepted and make a new question for that one. Stack Overflow is less a help group, and more of a question/answer repository.